# Dynamic GridLayout

Tags: android

I made an error in another class, that's why it didn't work. The code below seems to be correct

I'm trying to create a dynamic GridLayout. Inside another class, not this one, I have a method that designs rows and cols of my gridlayout. In the class below, i add some buttons to my GridLayout:

```
int buttons= 6;//the number of bottons i have to put in GridLayout
int buttonsForEveryRow = 3; // buttons i can put inside every single row
int buttonsForEveryRowAlreadyAddedInTheRow =0; // count the buttons added in a single rows
int columnIndex=0; //cols index to which i add the button
int rowIndex=0; //row index to which i add the button

for(int i=0; i < buttons;i++){          
    /*if numeroBottoniPerRigaInseriti equals numeroBottoniPerRiga i have to put the other buttons in a new row*/
    if(buttonsForEveryRowAlreadyAddedInTheRow ==buttonsForEveryRow ){
        rowIndex++; //here i increase the row index
        buttonsForEveryRowAlreadyAddedInTheRow  =0;  
        columnIndex=0; 
    }   

    Spec row = GridLayout.spec(rowIndex, 1); 
    Spec colspan = GridLayout.spec(columnIndex, 1);
    GridLayout.LayoutParams gridLayoutParam = new GridLayout.LayoutParams(row, colspan);
    gridLayout.addView(button_to_add,gridLayoutParam);

    buttonsForEveryRowAlreadyAddedInTheRow ++;
    columnIndex++;
```

In the following image you can see what i get: Buttons 3 and 6 are missing. I'm afraid I am not using `GridLayout.spec` properly.

[image]

Comment: What do you mean? You mean i have to set the cols and rows numbers inside the layout.xml file?

Comment: no set it through code

Comment: aaaa, i did it, inside another class.  I used `gridLayout.setColumnCount` and `gridLayout.setRowCount`. After setting them, i checked them with `getColumnCount` and `getRowCount` and i saw that rows and cols are correct. probably the problem is that i don't add my buttons to the GridLayout properly

Comment: OH made an error in another class, that's why it didn't work. Anyway thank you

Answer (score 16):

Using below code you can add image views to grid layout dynamically with column span and row span.

```
    gridLayout = (GridLayout) findViewById(R.id.gridview);

    gridLayout.removeAllViews();

    int total = 10;
    int column = 3;
    int row = total / column;
    gridLayout.setColumnCount(column);
    gridLayout.setRowCount(row + 1);
    for (int i = 0, c = 0, r = 0; i < total; i++, c++) {
        if (c == column) {
            c = 0;
            r++;
        }
        ImageView oImageView = new ImageView(this);
        oImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);            

        oImageView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(100, 100));

        Spec rowSpan = GridLayout.spec(GridLayout.UNDEFINED, 1);
        Spec colspan = GridLayout.spec(GridLayout.UNDEFINED, 1);
        if (r == 0 && c == 0) {
            Log.e("", "spec");
            colspan = GridLayout.spec(GridLayout.UNDEFINED, 2);
            rowSpan = GridLayout.spec(GridLayout.UNDEFINED, 2);
        }
        GridLayout.LayoutParams gridParam = new GridLayout.LayoutParams(
                rowSpan, colspan);
        gridLayout.addView(oImageView, gridParam);


    }
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. Please don't just post code as an answer. Explain your thoughts so we can better understand what you have done. Thanks.

Comment: @Strive55 I do not agree. He takes time to post code and if you want to, you can figure out yourself how it works. It not that big of a snippet and pretty easy to understand

Comment: @boy He is simply following the requirements of posting answers for this site.

Comment: If there's a total of 12 items then the row count would be 5, but we only need 4.